# Android left margin applied to right margin

Tags: android

In my xml layout I have a ViewAnimator which is made to fit the screen width and height. Inside this ViewAnimator, I have a ListView with left margin 10dp and right margin 10dp. The problem is that the left margin gets added to the right margin instead. The final result is that there is a 0dp margin on the left but a 20dp margin on the right. Working on 2.3.5. Has anybody had this problem?

Comment: I had this problem when I used corner in selector drawables. That was working in opposite direction(in 2.3.x alone). I changed my shape_drawable for 2.3.x alone.